# Android location manager getbestlocation return null

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I need a little help with some information/help about `LocationManager` in Android. I'm using this code to get user's specific information depending on his location,but in some situations I get `provider=null` (I'm not pretty sure when,because that exception was uploaded to our server and I can't reproduce it).

Here is the sample code :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crta = new Criteria(); 
crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); 
crta.setAltitudeRequired(false); 
crta.setBearingRequired(false); 
crta.setCostAllowed(true); 
crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);
Log.d("","provider : "+provider);
// String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 
updateWithNewLocation(location); 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, locationListener);
```

How can I when my provider is null and if there is a way to get the current location and use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code and dont forget that atleast one of your provider should be enabled

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crta = new Criteria();
crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
crta.setAltitudeRequired(true);
crta.setBearingRequired(true);
crta.setCostAllowed(true);
crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);
Log.d("","provider : "+provider);
// String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, locationListener);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 
//updateWithNewLocation(location);
```

Comment: i can't see the difference between your code and mine..except that two lines have changed their positions.

Comment: it was working before too, but the idea is how to prevent provider to be null...because in some situations (i don't know which because I can't reproduce them it's equal to null).

Comment: at the time where your device  dont have location or every provider was disabled you get null

Comment: in your code you were getting last known location before updaterequest in case you dont have location then it will give null after that start search

Comment: Bombastic i suggest you one more thing to get location of user try to use with handler or timer so that make your code wait until you will not get location this will give surity of not getting null